# Add a WCF REST Service to a mobile app developed with HTML5,Javascript, CSS

Tags: javascript, wcf, rest, mobile

I have implemented a WCF Service with SOAP/REST endpoints, which is published now to Windows Azure as a Cloud Service. This Cloud Service links together a Database and Storage, which are accesible by other existing clients.
I am now trying to implement a web mobile app using Javascript/HTML5.

Question: Is it possible to add the REST service reference to this web mobile app(as there are some operations from the service that we will need to use, as for other clients)? 
As far as I know it will be considered as a client and will consume my service properly right?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think as long as your mobile implements HTTP verbs (GET POST PUT DELETE) correctly you will be just fine, this is one of the benefits provided by open standards like REST.